Construct the point with two segments
Given a rational point P, return four integral points A, B, C, and D, such that the line segments AB and CD intersect only at P. To make it a bit more interesting, segment AB doesn't include A and B.
You can take input P as \$\left(\frac ab,\frac cd\right)\$ or \$\left(\frac ab,\frac cb\right)\$, and assume that b and d are the smallest possible positive integers for the value. a and c are also integers (not necessarily positive).
Shortest code wins.
Test cases (answers are not unique):
(1/2,1/2), aka. (1,1)/2 => (0,0)-(1,1);(0,1)-(1,0)
(1/2,-1/3), aka. (3,-2)/6 => (1,0)-(-2,-2);(0,0)-(6,-4)
(-5/2,5/4), aka. (-10,5)/4 => (0,0)-(-60,30);(-3,2)-(1,-4)
(1/2,0), aka. (1,0)/2 => (0,0)-(42,0);(0,1)-(1,-1)


Nice problem! I'm sure the outputs are not unique, but you could list at least one example for each test case. Also I would add test cases where the input point is itself integral in one or both coordinates. Can we output A=B=C=D=P in that case? Or maybe it's better to explicitly exclude such inputs from the problem.

May we output eight integers in some consistent order?

Solvers be warned, if you pick two fixed points as one endpoint of each segment, you'll fail when the point P is collinear because you'll get parallel segments.

Must the line segments only intersect at P? The question does not state this, but I think that may be what xnor is talking about (I don't understand their terminology though).

@JonathanAllan Outputting (0,0)-(a,c);(0,0)-(a,c) isn't a good idea, right?

But what if the line segments are different? The spec just does not say...

@JonathanAllan (0,0)-(a,c);(0,0)-(2a,2c) also no

In that case, could you please update the spec with this? Also, with the fact that zero-length line segments are acceptable (as per your response to lynn)?

"To make it a bit more interesting" = "To make those who already solved this do even more work, to address something that was previously allowed by my comment which I have now deleted" ... SIGH. -1

@JonathanAllan Agree. I tried to simplify description and there exist solution that break with it. Is my fault so agree your -1

Charcoal, 38 bytes
ＮθＮηＮζ≔⁺×³θζε≔⁻⊗θ×ε⊖⊗ζδＩ⟦ε⁰δ⊗ηε¹δ⊕⊗⁻ηζ

Try it online! Link is to verbose version of code. Takes (a/b,c/b) as input as three integers a, c, b. Explanation:
ＮθＮηＮζ

Input a, c and b.
≔⁺×³θζε

Calculate 3a+b.
≔⁻⊗θ×ε⊖⊗ζδ

Calculate 5a+b-6ab-2b².
Ｉ⟦ε⁰δ⊗ηε¹δ⊕⊗⁻ηζ

Output the lines (3a+b,0)-(5a+b-6ab-2b²,2c);(3a+b,1)-(5a+b-6ab-2b²,2c-2b+1).
Verify on Desmos.

Fails on -2 1 2

@att Indeed, it fails for a+b=0. Thanks for pointing that out!

@att New version is up, hopefully without any edge cases this time!

Wolfram Language (Mathematica), 28 25 22 17 bytes
#2{0,1,I,1+I-I#}&

Try it online!
Input [b, a+c*I] corresponding to the point \$\big(\frac ab,\frac cb\big)\$. Output four complex numbers, grouping the first and last two into segments. For tuple output, append /*ReIm (+6 bytes).
The segments \$\big((0,0),(1,0)\big)\$ and \$\big((0,1),(1,1-b)\big)\$ intersect at \$\big(\frac1b,0\big)\$. We can then rotate-scale about the origin so that \$(1,0)\$ coincides with \$(a,c)\$, and \$\big(\frac1b,0\big)\$ coincides with \$\big(\frac ab,\frac cb\big)\$. This yields the segments \$\big((0,0),(a,c)\big)\$, \$\big((-c,a),(a-c+bc, a+c-ab)\big)\$.

Ruby, 49 bytes
->a,c,b{[x=3*a+b,0,a+=a-x*b+=b-1,c+=c,x,1,a,c-b]}

Try it online!
Ruby port of Jonathan Allan's Python port of Neil's Charcoal solution.
Fixed by using the new formula from Neil's answer.

...which made the same line for a=-2, b=2, c=1 unfortunately. The spec has also since been amended to make AB end-point-exclusive. Feel free to update to Niel's latest which I imagine conforms to all of the new spec.

@JonathanAllan Indeed my comment has been upvoted so maybe that's a sign that I've got it right this time ;-)

Python3, 183 bytes:
lambda A,B,C:[*P(A/B,C/A,0),*P(A/B,C/A-B,A)]
from math import*
def P(p,a,b):
 q=[(floor(p),-1),(ceil(p),1)]
 for J,K in q:
  if round(T:=J*a+b,5)==int(T):yield J,T
  else:q+=[(J+K,K)]

Try it online!

f could be just lambda A,B,C:[*P(A/B,C/A,0),*P(A/B,C/A-B,A)]. Also yield J,T saves one.

@JonathanAllan Thank you, updated
